# Do bombardment counts for "invading planets"?

Tags: twilight-imperium, twilight-imperium-3rd-edition

The rules specify that:

> Ground Forces destroyed by bombardment are removed immediately, do not receive return fire, and will not participate in the upcoming Invasion Combat.

However, some political cards, action cards and special abilities refer to "When invading a planet with a Ground Force on it". So, if one invades a planet with Ground Forces on it, bombards them to death and then have a successful invasion, does that count for "when invading a planet with Ground Forces on it"?

(Sure, the Ground Forces did not count for the *invasion combat*, but they might count for the *invasion* itself as a whole..?)

Comment: "Some cards and abilities" you might want to list the names of those cards/abilities. The rules might differ in how bombardment and destroyed ground forces are handled. I.e. Dacxive Animator and Mechanized Units) Are you asking to see if the rules are consistent among cards/abilities or did you have a specific example in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [the rules](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Twilight%20Imperium%203/ti3rules.pdf) (pg. 12) refer to the term "invasion" as:

> **Hostile Landing (also called an "Invasion"):** A player lands units on a planet containing one or more of an enemy player's Ground Force units. This will result in an Invasion Combat during the Invasion Combat step.
>
> **If a player lands units on a planet that is controlled by an opponent, but does not contain any enemy Ground Forces**, the planet falls without resistance.

There are only three types of landings, Friendly, Neutral, or Hostile ("Invasion").

Comment: You can also see page 27, Ground Forces, under Controlling a Planet.

Comment: Great, that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I think that it would count. I agree that the *invasion Combat* is simply a part of the action of *invasion* and that the Ground Forces exist after the invasion has begun.

I think that this is partly supported by the [FAQ](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Twilight%20Imperium%203/ti3faq.pdf) (page 5):

> *Q: Is landing on a neutral planet considered an invasion for the purposes of “Imperial Peace”?*
>
> A: Yes. Planetary landings on neutral planets are considered invasions
>   for the purposes of Action and Political Cards.

This answer shows that *invasions* still count even when *invasion combat* does not occur.

Comment: I agree that an "invasion" occurs, but is it considered "invasion with a ground force on the planet?" I would assume it does, but can we try to get a clearer ruling on that?